To move files only; To copy folders only
Tested in Bash and Zsh:
copy nondot files                | cp ~/dir1/*     ~/dir2/
copy dot files                   | cp ~/dir1/.*    ~/dir2/
copy both nondot and dot files   | cp ~/dir1/{.,}* ~/dir2/

move nondot folders              | mv ~/dir1/*/     ~/dir2/
move dot folders                 | mv ~/dir1/.*/    ~/dir2/
move both nondot and dot folders | mv ~/dir1/{.,}*/ ~/dir2/


But is it possible, either in Bash or Zsh, without using find or test, and without Zsh globs, to move nondot, dot, and both nondot and dot files?
And to copy nondot, dot, and both nondot and dot folders (with their contents)?

To clarify: I look for 3 separate commands for each case. That is, 6 commands, that will form another 2 tables.

To select directories, you need zsh's / qualifier ~/dir1/*(/), ~/dir1/*/ also selects symlinks to directories and adds / to the paths. Using qualifiers is what you need here: mv ~/dir1/*(D^/) ~/dir2/ (^/ for non-directories including regular, symlink, fifo..., use . for regular only), why would you not want to use qualifiers (or use bash if you can use zsh)?

@StéphaneChazelas I'm simply trying to create a Bash vs. Zsh cheat sheet for my own use (whether I really need it is another question...). I know about Zsh's (/), (^/), (D^/), and I try to find corresponding solutions that will also work in Bash.

bash has no builtin equivalent to glob qualifiers and is generally a much more limited shell, so if you preclude find/test/loops, then the answer is going to be no unless you want to consider less standard alternatives to those such as tw or rawhide.

@StéphaneChazelas Well, thanks!

files .[!.]* * and directories .[!.]*/ */

@Jetchisel Doesn't seem to work for me, tried with bash 5.2 and zsh 5.9. Could you provide a copy-and-paste example?

echo .[!.]* * and echo .[!.]*/ */ works here, even dash and ash it works, downside is if there is nothing found the * expand literally. in bash nullglob can be used. not sure in other shells though.

The obvious solution to get a list of files based on types, besides specialised commands such as find, rh (rawhide), tw, fdfind is to use zsh glob qualifiers:

*: non-hidden files of any type
*(D): all files of any type
.* hidden files of any type

To which you can add (within parens)

/ . @ % p =: restricts to files of type directory regular symlink device pipe socket and much more
^/ file of any type except directory

Those can be prefixed with - for the check to be done after symlink resolution (and -@ like find's -xtype l would only return broken symlinks), and you can specify more than one, separated by , to list files of more than one type such as *(D=,%,p) for all sockets, devices and pipes (the D which turns on DOTGLOB for that glob applies globally).
bash has no equivalent, but you can always invoke zsh from bash if for some reason you have to use bash. For instance, to copy the hidden non-directory files:
zsh -c 'cp -- .*(^/) dest/'

Or another tool that can do it.
For instance, filtering a glob expansion based on type to pass to cp could be done with perl:
perl -e 'exec qw{cp --}, (grep {lstat && ! -d _} @ARGV), "dest/"' -- .*

(with the caveat that if there's no matching file, it will run cp -- dest/ which will report a syntax error).
Also beware that older versions of bash (prior to 5.2) used to include . and .. in the  expansion of .* (on systems and filesystems where readdir() returns them (most)). With those, you need to set the dotglob option and use [.]* instead of .* to exclude them.
